# How do I retrieve the exact value passed as an option value using Getopt::Long?

Tags: perl, getopt-long

I am trying the [Getopt::Long](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long) module to read command line arguments, but for some reason when I try to print the variable in a print statement it prints '1' and not the value that has been passed to the variable.

Example:

```
use Getopt::Long;
use warnings;
GetOptions(
                'name1' => \$name,
                'address' => \$add,
                'phone' => \$phone
        );
print "My name is $name , My address is $add, My phone number is $phone\n"
```

After running the above code with the following command:

```
perl getopt.pl --phone 77881100 --name1 Mart --address Ecity
```

The output is:

```
My name is 1 , My address is 1, My phone number is 1
```

I expected the output to be:

```
My name is Mart , My address is Ecity, My phone number is 77881100
```

Comment: Read the ["options with values"](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Options-with-values) section of the manual. In short: Use `'name1=s' => \$name` etc.

Comment: I heartily second the suggestion of [reading the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Options-with-values) when a module doesn't work the way you guessed it should :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;
GetOptions(
    'name1=s'   => \my $name,
    'address=s' => \my $add,
    'phone=s'   => \my $phone
);
print "My name is $name, My address is $add, My phone number is $phone\n"
```

see the section `Getopt::Long` section [Options with values](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long#Options-with-values)